# Matlab code for calculating consecutive points in particular radius

Tags: python, matlab

Problem: Given two parallel lists `x` and `y`, calculate the number of consecutive points within a certain radius `R` of a point given by index `i`. I am able to do this in Python, but having some trouble converting to Matlab.

Here's the code I wrote in Python:

```
R = 0.3
num_pts = 0
j = i
while j >= 0 and sqrt((x[i]-x[j])**2 + (y[i]-y[j])**2) <= R:
  num_pts += 1
  j -= 1
j = i + 1
while j < len(x) and sqrt((x[i]-x[j])**2 + (y[i]-y[j])**2) <= R:
  num_pts += 1
  j += 1
```

Variable `num_pts` now has the answer we want, but the following Matlab code won't do the same:

```
R = 0.3
num_pts = 0
j = i
while ( (j >= 1) & (sqrt(((x(i) - x(j))^2) + ((y(i) - y(j))^2)) <= R) )
  num_pts = num_pts + 1;
  j = j - 1; 
end

j = i + 1;

while ((j <= numel(x)) & (sqrt((x(i) - x(j))^2 + (y(i) - y(j))^2) <= R))
  num_pts = num_pts + 1;
  j = j + 1;
end
```

Anything helps, thanks in advance!

Edit: The problem is solved. The code above works (if it doesn't try using && instead of & in MATLAB).

Comment: It can probably be done with fewer lines and no loops. Can you give an example with inputs and desired output?

Comment: One example: consider the points (3,4),(1,1),(0,0),(2,4),(10,10),(0.5,0.5) in that order. Then `x = [3 1 0 2 10 0.5]` and `y = [4 1 0 4 10 0.5]` and let `i = 3` i.e. the point (0,0) and let `r = 5` Then the expected answer is 4 because there are 4 consecutive points in a circle of radius 5 around the point (0,0).

Comment: your example works find. Are you aware that the indexing in Python starts at 0, but in MATLAB at 1? So the code won't return the same result if you choose `i` to be the same in both languages (you must choose `i_MATLAB = i_Python+1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The given code works (if it doesn't try using && instead of & in MATLAB, else something else may be the problem).